# como modifico los datos en un dataframe, creado a partir de una web?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

No logro modificar un dataframe que creé basado en datos de una web, baje los datos con la llibrería BeautifulSoup y luego creé el dataframe con Pandas, y ahora no logro modificarlo como lo necesito.

**El código que uso para conseguir el contenido de la URL**

```
# specify url
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M'

# import the BeautifulSoup library so we can parse HTML and XML documents
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

# parse the HTML from our URL into the BeautifulSoup parse tree format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

print(soup.prettify())
```

**Imagen del resultado de Wikipedia:**

[image]

**Código con el que intento generar el `DataFrame`**

```
# tables 
wikitable = soup.find('table', class_='wikitable sortable')
wikitable
# loop at wikiweb

A = []
B = []
C = []

for row in wikitable.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    if len(cells) == 3:
        A.append(cells[0].find(text=True))
        B.append(cells[1].find(text=True))
        C.append(cells[2].find(text=True))

# Making a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns=['Postal Code'])
df['Borough']=B
df['Neighborhood']=C
df
```

**El resultado que obtengo como `DataFrame` generado:**

[image]

Y hasta aquí todo iba bien, pero no logro modificarlo! Este es el código que no logro hacer que funcione:

el siguiente código es para ignorar del dataframe los rows que tengan 'Not assigned':

```
df = df[df.Borough != 'Not assigned'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

el siguiente código es para combinar las filas que compartan el mismo codigo postal, en una fila con los barrios separados con una coma:

```
dfgroup = df.groupby(['Postal Code','Borough'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas? ¿Qué resultado te da esto?

Comment: actualmente no me cambia nada. Pero deberìa, la primera linea de codigo, ignorar del dataframe, los rows que tengan la palabra 'Not assigned'. y la siguiente línea deberìa  agrupar .

Comment: Probablemente es ' Not assigned', o 'Not assigned '. intenta ver de la columna, los valores únicos y así ver como están guardados. `df.Borough.unique().tolist()` o sino solo aplica `df.Borough.str.contains('Not assigned')`